# Where is the OSGi Compendium for 4.3?

Tags: osgi

Somewhat silly question I'm sure, but I'm not familiar with the OSGi specification process.  When should we expect a Compendium for version 4.3 of the specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are still working on it. Hope to complete the spec work this week and then enter balloting. I expect it would be made public in Jan 2012.

Comment: Thanks.  I incorrectly assumed that the compendium and the core specifications were more tied at the hip.  Is there a preview of what's changing in 4.3?  I've seen early drafts of the service platform; is that the same thing as the compendium?

Comment: Service Platform is an overall name. OSGi has release early drafts of various RFCs. Some of these RFCs will contribute to the Compendium 4.3 release as will Enterprise specifications and new Residential specifications.

Comment: As of early May 2012, Compendium version 4.3 is still not available. I wonder what's holding it up.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It was held up in OSGi's internal approval process. It has been approved and should be published next week.

Comment: FYI. I just published the Compendium 4.3 spec for download. http://blog.osgi.org/2012/05/compendium-43-and-residential-43.html

Comment: Here was today's sequence: Reluctantly impound Compendium version 4.2 into my company's Ivy repository, test it, check my RSS reader, see this announcement, and slap my forehead. If only I had put "play reading" before work...